# jQuery Validate- throws error all time

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I wrote a custom validator for jquery validator plugin .

Problem is, the custom validator I wrote is throwing error for anything I input. If I input plain text, it will still show error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a validator your function should return `false` if the `value` matches the `regex` and `true` if not:

```
$.validator.addMethod('noHTMLallowed', function(value) {
  return !/<(.|\n)*?>/.test(value);
}, 'It contains HTML tags');
```